# Website Files Permissions

Tags: bash, scripts, ftp

I am trying to set all folders and subfolders (directories) to 755 and all files that are contained by folders and subfolders to 644.

I don't know how can I do this from 1-2 commands. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can...

This command sets all directories to permissions 755

```
find /your/selected/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and this one sets all files to permissions 644

```
find /your/selected/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

For better understanding of this command I suggest ExplainShell: http://explainshell.com/

Comment: Using `+` in place of `\;` is a better option as it will fork `-exec` only once..

Comment: @heymall: Depends on the number of files, it can cause "Argument list too long"